# Coworker provided wrong information and told me to use it which I did unknowingly

Tags: colleagues, problem-solving

Coworker who has a higher title told me to use information for a project which that section is used to determine the basis for the project. I was told to use that section and not touch it because they spent a lot of time on it. I noticed some things seemed off but I was told not to touch it in those exact words. Our boss and coworker often have discussions where coworker instructs me from there based on their discussion yet the boss does not himself include me or provide me with the Information so this was another scenario which they had a discussion and was what I thought approved by boss or boss instructed them on the details to then provide me. So I used that and built the rest of the project analysis which was reviewed with my boss already and approved. Now coworker said oh things look wrong and go back to that file and use it and I said that is the file you instructed me to use. They said oh use this column instead they are not sure where another column is from. What do I do? I said this is what you had told me to use which I did and now you are saying use a different column but this was already done and at this point it is just another check before processing but my work was based on this section that coworker instructed me to use.

Comment: What is your goal? To be included in the discussions with the boss? To not have to do the work again? Something else ?

Comment: I just do not want to be blamed for something that was instructed to use. Coworker is now changing the information which is fine things happen but they are not taking responsibility and trying to shift focus. How do I approach manager with this new Information and ask to avoid another situation should it happen again

Comment: People make mistakes. And sometimes you have to redo work. That's life. Complaining to your boss will get you nowhere. Just let your boss know about the revised timelines due to changing information. No need to make a big deal out of this.

Comment: I don't understand the dilemma. A mistake was made. Now you've been asked to resolve it. What's your concern? Why not make the change as instructed?

Comment: "What do I do?"  Correct the mistake and move on.   In the future, you should reach out to your boss for instructions since your coworker apparently cannot be trusted.

Comment: Did this situation cause any negative impact on your work reputation ? Did the manager think that you did not do a good job because you simply follow the coworker's instruction ? -- If there is no negative impact on your work reputation, then everything should be fine. Mistakes happen, and the mistakes are now corrected by the coworker or team. If no body blames you for the mistake, then move on.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to write a quick note summarizing meetings and scoping out the work mandate as you understand it.  Email it to yourself and the coworker, so you both have a view of it.  Or have a doc you both share, but make sure you have some version tracking on it, so you can see what changes over time.

This doesn't have to be contentious - it can be a way of keeping you both sane, and can be useful tool, even when the work is working just fine.  Generally meeting notes and action items are just useful.  But where you've had areas of contention, this can help both clear it up and provide clarity on who made what judgement calls.  If you write up the work and your more senior coworker approves it, then that coworker owns it as much as you do.

In this case, the ideal set of notes would have been a quick write up of the work in the beginning with exactly what source materials to use and what do to with them.  If there was specific column mentioned, that would be in your write up.

With that said - work is generally iterative.  It maybe also be that in your company, there really is no expectation of perfection here, and if moving from one column to another is as easy as changing a formula, it may just be the minor tweaks involved in vetting work.  In which case - change it and move on.  If a change is low cost and easy to make, it's not the kind of thing to spend lots of time capturing up front.

Another trick is to review your finished work with the coworker before you go to the boss.  If that person is responsible for the quality of your work together (implied, since they are giving you detailed direction...), then they should also have the chance to review it with you before you go to the bigger meeting.  I would only really worry about disagreements if you sense that it's a high-blame culture.  I've worked in plenty of places where it's just assumed that the team succeeds and fails together, and we don't get hung up on blaming people, we aim to innovate, mess up, fix it, and move on quickly more than we worry about being perfect and getting everything right.

Comment: Exactly this - put it in writing (Email) and get written confirmation, CC in your boss etc.